# Generating family for box topology

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X_{\alpha}$, $\alpha\in\Lambda$ is a family of topological spaces and the product set $\Pi_{\alpha\in\Lambda}X_{\alpha}$ is equipped with the box topology. Can we find a generating family of functions for this topology like the product topology generated by the family of projections?

Comment: A similar question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3095816/513190) was asked here and attracted some attention, but only a very minor discussion in the comments. It seems like this is a hard question.